# Как сделать кнопку для отправки данных с форм в виде прямоугольника с границей и текстом внутри?

Tags: html, css

Вставлять в виде картинки не предлагать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь](http://livetools.uiparade.com/form-builder.html) можно сгенерировать css и html для форм

Answer (score 1):

Убираем,этим круглые углы,и делаем прямыми.

```
border-radius: 0px;
```

С помощью атрибута value,у кнопки ,пишем в ней текст:

```
<input type="submit" value="Текст,который хочешь,чтобы был на кнопке">
```

Далее играясь с width,и height,делаете свою кнопку-прямоугольником)А потом добавляем к себе в закладки сайт http://htmlbook.ru/)Там и про границу найдете,и про все)

Answer (score 0):

[@ололо](/users/4501/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE), **[ловите](http://jsfiddle.net/Eyakw/7/)**, надеюсь поможет.

P.s. Не совсем понял Ваш вопрос, так как кнопка отправки данных формы, изначально представляет из себя прямоугольник с текстом и границей.

Удачи.